# PhpED: Fastest way to open a file?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phped

I'm looking for a faster way to open files in PhpED projects.

The way I do it is to pull up the Workspace pane with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (explorer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>), then <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to find the file. This is not very effective; it takes to much time to locate the file, mostly since <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> jumps some 50-100 files/folders at a time.

I think I'm looking for something similar to Textmate's "go to file".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even I have faced the same issue.
On the project if you type a file or folder name, phped will take you there.
But this is not very helpful if you have lots of file and many duplicates in there.

What I do is "everything". Whenever I need a file, I click on everything tool in the taskbar then type the filename or type folder/filename and then double click it to open in PHPed.

http://lifehacker.com/5054669/everything-finds-windows-files-as-you-type

And yes I presume you are using windows like majority of PHPEd users.

Comment: How can I make it search only the current project?

Comment: use folder name, for example you want to search config.inc.php which is in folder called appsoft. Just type appsoft/config.inc.php and the file will appear.

Comment: Cool app, very fast. But then I would have to write the full path, eg project/foo/bar/file.php. I'll give it a try, but an app with smarter search would be great.

Comment: If it would save the sorting, that would help a lot. If I sort by last modified, the most likely file comes first.

Comment: Woa! Found that the latest alpha had soo many more options. awesome! http://forum.voidtools.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=592

Comment: Been using this for a couple of hours now, works good. Thanks

Comment: What you need really is the way Eclipse handles opening files with Ctrl-Shift-R and functions with Ctrl-Shift-T. That's an amazing productivity tool. I hate PDT for debugging PHP though - PHPEd is much better. I suggested these shortcuts to them before but I don't think they caught on. :( Ah, and Everything didn't work for me - it didn't see the network drive where my code is shared.

Comment: Really looking forward to [intype](http://intype.info). http://twitpic.com/2x86ib/full

Answer (score 2):

In v9 I can open file from a dropdown Ctrl+Shift+N - I just type for example abc and will display all files matching *abc* pattern. It certainly supports regular file patterns too.
And btw, I don't use it so frequently, used to use Workset feature -- each new work/fix/feature I start with opening new Workset. Don't mess with Workspace. Each workspace may have multiple worksets -- a list of open files, with their breakpoints, with appropriate active project, and so forth. It fully supports current context, so I don't have any problems switching between worsets when I need to return back to some previous things I did some weeks ago.  Good job is done at NuSphere. Damn fast IDE.

Comment: Yes, this new feature is really cool. But I am also facing some problems with it - suddenly it searches only files in the current folder (no subfolders) or sth like that.. If it works, it is fine, but obviously there are still some bugs..